# Composer list available packages

Tags: composer-php, repository, bitbucket

we can list all available composer packages by running

```
composer show -a
```

and it shows all the packages available on packagist... but in my `composer.json` I have the folowing configuration:

```
...
"repositories": [
    {
       "type": "git",
       "url": "https://bitbucket.org/........."
    }
 ]
 ...
```

so I was expecting that `composer show -a` was looking for all the packages available in all the repositories defined inside the composer.json file but in this case it shows me all the packages available at packagist even if I didn't included it... how can I list all the available packages at this bitbucket address that I addded in my composer.json file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `--all` switch instead of `-a` (`--available`):

```
composer show --all
```

> - `--all`: List all packages available in all your repositories.
>
> <sub>https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to *not* show "packagist" and only show packages that are added via the `repositories` field?

Comment: [Yes](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#disabling-packagist-org).

Answer (score 4):

You can disable `packagist.org` and use `composer show --all`

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "packagist.org": false
        }
    ]
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#disabling-packagist-org